# Coordinates of a point between two other points and know the distance from starting point and target point

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

How can i Find the Coorfinate of H.If There are three point that are collinear A,H,C . If it is known the two points that are at both ends like  A(1.3,2.6)  ,   C(8.1,13.7) and the distance of  AH is  3.170958  . So how can I find the coordinates of  H  ? Here  A is the starting point and  C is the end point.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geometry / mathematics instead of programming / coding / programming tools / software algorithms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find length of AC and apply formula to x and y coordinates

```
  H = A + (C-A)* Len(AH) / Len(AC)
```

It is [linear interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation). Geometrically - law of similar triangles. Hypotenuses ratio (length)  is equal to  cathetus ratio (coordinate)

Comment: can you please explain why it works? actually  I don't understand why it works?